# The meaning of -보있다

Tags: grammar, verb, north-korean

Sometimes I face verb + 보있다 construction.

E.g. 바라보있다, 들어보있다. How this construction changes the verb meanings?

Comment: Just a note. It might be “보았다,” the auxiliary verb “보다” in the past tense. And the verb “바라보다” was two different words, but is a single word now.

Comment: I meet the usage 바라보있는. In past tense, the verb 바라보다 would be 바라본/바라보던.
Also, 들었어보있습니다 (if I not mishear), for army units entering the parade square.

Comment: Hmm, then “-보있다” would be a North Korean's own thing that the southern language doesn't have.

Comment: If I search "보있다" in the google, it shows me some videos which contain 놀아보있다 in description. Videos from the south.

--https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_Pg6oeZslQ--
and
--https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDMPhQ-62N8--

Comment: Oh, well, those are, you know, children's grammar mistakes. Considering their spacing, word spellings, and the videos. `발리송을 사서갔고놀아보있다.` and `액책괴물로놀아보있다`.

Comment: Did you hear this or see it?  It looks like a mistake.  Could it be 바라보았다 (past tense) or 바라봐 있다 (be staring) or 바라보이다 (passive; uncommon for this verb)?

Comment: ---https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2rtHNnYoXag---
32:52-32:54
Yes, maybe it's a conjugated form of 바라보이다 (바라보이는)

Also, I hear something like 들었어보있습니다 from the parade video:
---https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o0XYFW9G3eE---
From 1:24:11 to 1:24:16 the narrator says that the cavalry entered the square.
From 1:39:05 to 1:39:12 the narrator says that the vehicle columns entered the square one after another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

북한어 north-korean chose a vowel "l" than "ㅏ", compared to 남한어
south-korean, sometimes.

북한어 (남한어) : 그러니끼 (그러니까 thus), 수집다(수줍다 be shy),
부시다(부수다 break), 내놓이다(내놓아 지다 be shown), 엮이다(엮어
지다 be involved)

Long ago, gag man followed north-korean speaking for a satire or
joy. In my thought, it is an easy technic. For instance, 내레
그러니끼 ... 그렇습니끼 ? (I thus ... is it true ?). That is, when
we change ㅏ into ㅣ, it sounds like north-korean.

In case of 보았다, I do not know a north-korean of it (I do not know
whether it is an influence of north), and exact origin. At any rate,
in the internet, many people use 보있다. Maybe we can not see it 10
years ago. In my thought, 보있다 is more cute so that it represents
an intimacy or a charm in internet.

Comment: 보았다 is the past of 보다 in the North, too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Korean speaker from South and I've never heard or seen `보있다` used as verb.
At first I thought it's probably a misspelled word of `보았다`, but if that's not the case, I guess it could be `뵀다`.

- 바라보았다. 들어 보았다.
- 바라뵀다. 들어 뵀다.

Those all make sense and mean the same. `space` + `보았다` or `space` + `뵀다` would be used when people try out something unusual. If there is a difference between those two, it's that `뵀다` feels much more informal and non-standard than `보았다`.

Answer (score -1):

The meaning of 보았다 itself is for the past term of "see" or "보다".
but (verb)+보았다 is most similar to "I have (verb)."

Comment: the question asks for 보있다